# What is not an expression in the Wolfram Language?

Tags: core-language, language-design, education

*Everything Is an Expression*, or

[*In fact, everything you type into the Wolfram Language is treated as an expression*.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html)

The cool cliché confused me for a long time. The following two statements are obvious:

1. People create nouns to separate things, e.g., sun is different from moon, today is different from yesterday.
2. 'Expression' is a noun.

If ["Everything in the Wolfram Language is a symbolic expression"](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/symbolic-expressions/) is correct, the word 'expression' is useless in separating things in the Wolfram Language. Does that mean that we do not need the word *expression* the Wolfram Language? So, I ask the question: What is **NOT** an expression in the Wolfram Language?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I think one should realize that "Expression" is a technical term in Mathematica.  And they are represented internally as trees (try applying `TreeForm` to any input or output of Mathematica).  The non-trivial part of this statement is that even things like code blocks: `Module[{x=1, y=0}, ... ]` is a (single) expression.  Its usefulness is most evident when it comes to matching pattens.

Comment: You could clarify your question immensely if you were aware of the *use/mention* distinction.  When you write "...the noun expression..." do you mean the noun called "expression" or instead the *noun-expression*?  Clarity in these questions is paramount.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I mean expression is a noun in grammar. It is not a verb, right?

Comment: @Kuba you are correct, and I'v modified the question.

Comment: @wangtwo:  It would help immensely if you used the standard English approach of putting into quotation marks a word when you're referring to the *word* rather than the thing the word refers to.  For example, it is correct to write:   "'verb' is a noun."  It is meaningless to write:  "verb is a noun."  If you're unfamiliar with this fundamental use/mention distinction, I urge you to do a web search on it and learn it carefully.

Comment: @QuantumDot Thanks for your comment. I know expression is a technical term in computer science, which is not the same in mathematics. In C, we distinct variable, expression and statement.  So there is something that is different with expression in C.  From [ExpressionStructure](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ExpressionStructure.html) I know all expressions in  the Wolfram Language have a uniform tree-like structure.  I apply `TreeForm` to `For[i = 0, i < 4, i++, Print[i]]`, e.g., `TreeForm[For[i = 0, i < 4, i++, Print[i]]]`, but the output is Null.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork As a non-native English speaker I follow you suggestions to modify the question. Thank you.

Comment: I can't really discern a practical answerable question here. You seem to be debating the phrasing, but that's not a question.  The point is that there is no fundamental difference between code and data in Mathematica, unlike in many other languages (such as C). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity

Comment: The reason is that the code has already evaluated.  Try instead `TreeForm[Hold[For[i = 0, i < 4, i++, Print[i]]]]`

Comment: A comma is a valid syntactical element, but is not expression. It is, I believe, the only true delimiter in the Wolfram Language.

Comment: The universe of discourse is Programming Languages, not WL ⊂ PL; and the sentence makes a non-tautological statement about it: "(t ∈ Typing && t ∈ WL) => t ∈ Expressions[WL]", to distinguish WL from C etc.  (They are also defining the term "expression" for W in the tutorialL, to be used throughout the documentation.)

Answer (score 15):

Comments like `(* blah *)` are not expressions.

```
ToExpression["(* blah *)"]
```

returns `Null`.

Furthermore, anything that is syntax (e.g. `+`) is not a complete expression.

For

```
ToExpression["+"]
```

You will get a

```
Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed .
```

Comment: Why is a comment not an expression?

Comment: @Nasser it doesn't even survive parsing and is stripped before `MakeExpression`. So there is no structure we could discuss.

Comment: @Kuba  I see. I thought since it has opening `(*` and ending with `*)`, and M knows about `(*` and matching `*)`, so in a sense, M "parse" and reads it at one points. But fair enough.

Comment: @Nasser parsers know about it and won't let it to the kernel, so since it doesn't even exist during evaluation the question is, is it part of the WL? :)

Comment: I think a comment is part of WL. Because if there is no closing *) then M complains. But this is a deep philosophical question we are entering. If a comment is an expression or not.  It is not easy to decide. You seem to say, if something do not enter the kernel, then it is not an expression. This is I think is a new view and interesting way to look at things.

Comment: I just found a logical flaw in this argument. The question is asking what is not an expression in _Wolfram language_. Since a comment is not part of _Wolfram language_, then it does not qualify. It is not even in the set. The thing which is not an expression must be something in the _Wolfram language_ but also not be an expression at the same time !

Comment: A Mathematica package (.wl or .m file with BeginPackage ... EndPackage ) is not an expression, unfortunately. If it would be, code-reuse, refactoring, etc.  would be easier, maybe.

Comment: @RolfMertig Kuba had pointed out that package is not an expression. So I'd changed 'mathematica' to 'the Wolfram Language' in this question.

Comment: @Nasser you assumed the comment isn't an expression so it isn't part of the Wolfram Language. Is this acceptable? I'd say we are back to the question whether we can talk about WL "before" parsing or only after. Which I don't think is tough question but I'm not qualified :)